# Resize image in the frontend, javascript, before sending it to S3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I am using React Dropzone for the file upload. I then generate the S3 putObject signedURL and send the image to S3 using axios.

It looks something like this:

```
const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({
  onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
    const image = acceptedFiles[0]

    getS3SignedUrl(...)
      .then(path => {
        const options = {...}

        //????

        return axios.put(path, image, options)
      })

  }
})
```

Everything is working fine but the images are very big. I would like to reduce the width/height of the image, scale it down and maybe reduce the quality before sending it to S3.

I looked at some similar question but I can't figure out what is the best lib/ way of doing it.

Can someone help me with an example?

Comment: Check this if you want the same
https://gist.github.com/torgeir/eab493939ec9cac1ad3f

Comment: try this dep https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-file-resizer

Comment: Cheers, both of the methods are fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-image-file-resizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-file-resizer) package.

How to use:

First, wrap this resizer:

```
const resizeFile = (file) => new Promise(resolve => {
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(file, 300, 300, 'JPEG', 100, 0,
    uri => {
      resolve(uri);
    },
    'base64'
    );
});
```

And then use it in your async function:

```
const onChange = async (event) => {
    try {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        const image = await resizeFile(file);
        console.log(image);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-imgpro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-imgpro) library. And below how to use.

```
import React from 'react';
import ProcessImage from 'react-imgpro';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    src: '',
    err: null
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ProcessImage
        image='http://365.unsplash.com/assets/paul-jarvis-9530891001e7f4ccfcef9f3d7a2afecd.jpg'
        resize={{ width: 500, height: 500 }}
        colors={{
          mix: {
            color: 'mistyrose',
            amount: 20
          }
        }}
        processedImage={(src, err) => this.setState({ src, err})}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

And processed image would store in the state.

Comment: It is not for my use case but it is very interesting anyway.

Comment: Can any of you help with this I'm really stuck https://shorturl.at/lAMY3 @Kocur4d

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary has great features including what you want. All you have to do is use the SDK and then send the image along with the parameters resize the image there and will return the processed image URL along with the image and stored in the cloud of your cloudinary account. I really rely on Cloudinary specifically NodeJS SDK. You can see the SDK documentation for ReactJS.
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_integration

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of clientside resizing, ie shrinking the image you are sending over the wire.